# Irrational equation high school

Tags: radicals, radical-equations

I've been trying to solve this one without success... can anybody help me?

The result should be $x=\frac{17}{16}$ and it's correct, I've already checked.

This is the equation:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {x+2} - \sqrt x}+\frac{2}{\sqrt {x+4} + \sqrt x}=2$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Rationalize the denominators.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x}}{2},$$
and
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{x+4} + \sqrt{x}} = \frac{2\sqrt{x+4} - 2\sqrt{x}}{4},$$
and so we find
$$\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x+4} = 4.$$

Thus,
$$\sqrt{x+4} = 4 - \sqrt{x+2},$$
and so we find that

$$x+4 = x + 18 - 8\sqrt{x+2},$$
$$8\sqrt{x+2} = 14,$$
$$x+2 = \frac{196}{64},$$
and so
$$x = \frac{68}{64} = \frac{17}{16}.$$

Comment: Thanks, it was so easy...